# C Bubblesort in LinkedList

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, swap

I'm trying to sort a doubly linked list, but I'm having some trouble. I'm a noob in C and I guess my problem is with pointers..

I just can't see how to swap two positions inside the list and so maybe that's the issue.

I tryied to sort it by using Bubblesort, even knowing that it's complexity is not so good because, how I'm still learning, thought that it was an easy way to start.

I also tryied reading some things about swaping elements in a linkedlist and how to sort them, but I'm really stuck with this problem...

PS: I started the for with the m->next cause my list has a header(m).

PS2:I'm getting the error "request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union", and don't know how to fix it

```
struct segment {
   int x, y;   /// position
   char c;   // letter 
   struct segment* next;
   struct segment* prev; 
};


void sortingSegments(struct segment* m) {
   struct segment **j; struct segment **i;

   for(i = &((m->next)->next); i !=NULL; i = i->next) {
          for(j = &(m->next); j == i; j = j->next) {
              if ((*j)->c > (*i)->c) {
                  struct segment **aux;
                  aux = i;
                  (*aux)->next = (*i)->next;
                  (*aux)->prev = (*i)->prev;

                  i = j;
                  (*i)->next = (*j)->next;
                  (*i)->prev = (*j)->prev;

                  j = aux;
                  (*j)->prev = (*aux)->prev;
                  (*j)->next = (*aux)->next;
              }
          }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your problem is with pointers. You must pass the address of the list, not just a pointer to it (`m`) to handle the cases where the first node changes position and the list address changes. So you will need `sortingSegments(struct segment **m)`, then you can simply use `segment *j, .. *i` and adjust the remaining level of indirection. In the event the first node is swapped, do not forget to set `*m = new_first_node_address;` or your list will break following the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments and try to understand the linking of nodes.

It is based on the [simple bubble sort described in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation).

```
void sortingSegments(struct segment** m) {
    struct segment *i, *tmp, *prev, *next;
    int swapped = 1;
    /*
     * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation
     *  n = length(A)
     *  repeat
     *    swapped = false
     *    for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
     *      //if this pair is out of order
     *      if A[i - 1] > A[i] then
     *        // swap them and remember something changed
     *        swap(A[i - 1], A[i])
     *        swapped = true
     *      end if
     *    end for
     *  until not swapped
     */

     // looping until no more swaps left
     while (swapped) { 
        swapped = 0;
        // we begin from the second item at each iteration
        for (i = (*m)->next; i; i = i->next) { 
            // we need to swap i with i->prev
            if (i->prev->c > i->c) { 
                prev = i->prev;
                next = i->next;
                // swapping first and second elements,
                // so update m to reflect the change made 
                // to the head of the list
                if (prev == *m) { 
                    *m = i;
                } 
                // so there is a prev of prev, update that two links
                else { 
                    prev->prev->next = i;
                    i->prev = prev->prev;
                }
                // so there is a next, update that two links
                if (next) { 
                    next->prev = prev;
                    prev->next = next;
                }
                // no next element, mark the end of the list
                else { 
                    prev->next = NULL;
                }
                // this is obvious, prev now becomes i's next
                prev->prev = i; 
                i->next = prev;

                // this is needed to reflect the change in i
                i = prev; 
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```